# How to update the value in cells in a grid

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

i have a Grid and i have  4 rows and I need to update the 4th row based on the inputs in the 1st,2nd and 3rd row values .
Example :

1st when  you enter 1 the total in the 4th row should be 1 
when you enter 1 in 1st row and 2 in 2nd row the total shoud be 3 .
Should we use java script as these rows are in a grid when we hit a pop up on the page .
let me know if I am missing anything

Comment: Infragistics help on summary row http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/WebDataGrid_Summary_Row.html

Comment: What grid are you using Win Forms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: I am using Infragistics ultra webgrid

Answer (score 5):

This question has been already discussed in the IG forum at: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/77638.aspx

Here's what I wrote there:

> You could handle the AfterCellUpdateHandler. It will fire after a
>   cell’s value has been changed so in it you could look through the cell
>   values and calculate the sum. After that you can change the last
>   cell’s value. For example:
>
> ```
> function UltraWebGrid1_AfterCellUpdateHandler(gridName, cellId){
>
>     var cell = igtbl_getCellById(cellId);
>     var totalCell = cell.Row.getCellFromKey("Total");
>     var sum = 0;
>     for (var i = 1; i < cell.Row.cells.length-1; i++) {
>         sum += cell.Row.getCell(i).getValue();
>     }
>     cell.Row.getCellFromKey("Total").setValue(sum);
> }
> ```
>
> Please refer to the attached sample. In it if you change the value in
>   any of the cells the value of the related cell from the column “Total”
>   will be calculated based on the new values.
>
> Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: just giving a link to a page is bad practice. what if this link is no longer available?

Comment: Really, I appreciate the presence of Infragistcs representative here, but I think you are not following the rules. An answer consisting of just a link is not considered a good answer also if the link points to the correct solution. Just retype here the answer and give yourself the credit due.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value) + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value) ;
```

In the [ ], you will have to enter desired index of row or column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unbound field 
see this example [Unbound field](http://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/sample/data-grid/unbound-fields)

here you can see unbound field of subtotal,SalesTax and Total and code done at cs side in InitializeRecord event.